# Divide all numbers in a file by 10 (or delete last digit of every number)

Tags: regex, replace, numbers, division, digit

Good morning all,
I have a series of files in which some lines are text-only and do not matter, and others which look like this:

```
    size=xxxx
```

These numbers range from single-digit to six digits. What I would like to do is divide every number in the file by 10, with a minimum of 1, and with all remaining whole numbers. Something just as good can be achieved by deleting the last digit in every line which ends with a number of some sort (I can then find and replace those lines which deleted the only digit). So, for instance

```
    size=32451
    ...
    size=9423
    ...
    size=123452
    ...
    size=3
    ...
    size=31
```

becomes

```
    size=3245
    ...
    size=942
    ...
    size=12345
    ...
    size=1
    ...
    size=3
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: What software or programming language are you using?

Comment: size=3 becomes size=1??

Comment: Please **clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need**. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question

Answer (score 2):

If your software/programming language allows you to use conditional replacement (e.g. Notepad++), replace:

```
(?<=size=)(\d{1,5})?\d
```

with `(?1\1:1)` (or `(?1$1:1)`).

Otherwise, you have to do 2 separate replacements: first replace: `(?<=size=)(\d{1,5})\d` with `\1` (or `$1`), then `(?<=size=)\d` with `1`.

Comment: This site is amazing. Thank you!